# chained planning entity fixed-referencing another

Tags: optaplanner

hi optaplanner experts

I have a chained planning variable within an entity. in addition to that, I'd like to have each instance of the entity referncing *fixed, "final"* list of another entities of the same type (call them siblings). 
this list is not a planning variable, of course.

does this break the chain principle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't. The chained principle only applies to the planning variable that is chained.

Even if an entity has 2 or more chained plannings variables, they are independent: each on it's own must respect the chained principles, but they do not affect each other (unless you add constraints of course).